# PDO SQLlite not creating database in directory

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am using the following php code

```
try
{
    $file_db = new PDO('sqlite:/databasepath/users.sqlite3');
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    // Print PDOException message
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

and it displays `SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`

However when I don't use a path it works fine, like this

```
$file_db = new PDO('sqlite:users.sqlite3');
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Are you sure your webserver has write permissions in the directory you give in the path?

Comment: I mean it works without the path so shouldnt it be fine? And I'm pretty sure it has permissions as `mkdir()` and `file_put_contents()` works fine

Comment: Does `file_put_contents()` work fine **with** the exact same path?

Comment: Yes it does.  I Have no idea whats going on

Comment: It doesn't work like this either `$file_db = new SQLite3('path/to/mysqlitedb.db');`